# SSRS Report - Sum Header - NOT in Group

Tags: visual-studio, t-sql, reporting-services, group-by, sum

How do I sum (in header row) the values in the grouped row below?

Instead of the word 'Performance' I want to say sum the field below. The highlighted field is called: Textbox119

[image]

When I say in the row above

```
=sum(ReportItems!Textbox119.Value)
```

I get the following error message:

```
The Value expression for the text-run Textbox... uses an aggregate function on a report item. Aggregate functions can be used only on report items contained in page headers and footers.
```

If this is the wrong way to add the rows below ... How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Right mouse the group field you wish to total, select add total, select before.
Adjacent to the new Total label enter the aggregate function and field name you desire, for example: =Count(Fields!Venue.Value)

Comment: I can't add a row, I have to use the header row -- because I have to reference the data in a field elsewhere. (As as i understand it in order to have a textbox elsewhere to reference a field that field has to be a header field.

Comment: Only if you are referencing ReportItems!, you should, where possible, reference the Fields! from your dataset as SuperSimmer 44 suggested in his answer.

Comment: @AlanSchofield i tried referencing the fields, there were issues because of the data. So that idea went out the window. What I had hoped to try was header value 1 - has 55, the other 0. Sum the two, and get me the correct answer.